How to wrap text separated in several divs at if it was in one div?
<div style="width: 200px; background-color: lightblue">
<div style="display:flex " >
<div>This is some text.</div><div>This is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>
</div>

<div style="width: 200px; background-color: lightyellow">
<div style="display:flex " >
<div>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>

I'm looking for a way to style the divs in the lightblue div so that the text looks like the text in the lightyellow div.

start by removing display:flex then make the div display:inline

I would suggest you remove ALLL style= and use CSS and classes perhaps.

@Mark  I'm using bootstrap in my project, I made an example with inline classes for the sake of this post.

<div style="width: 200px; background-color: lightblue">
<div>
<div style="display:inline ">This is some text.</div><div style="display:inline ">This is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>
</div>

The solution @temani-afif proposed, it works!
